# Crashes after brought back from background

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

I have an app pretty much completed at this point.. there's alot of animation methods being used and it's based on a storyboard using ARC.  At the finish point it now seems that a user will crash occasionally when the app is brought back from the background (the tablet locks) and app is still lives but is brought back to foreground.  When you click a button.. boom.

Any general advice to deal with a problem like this.. Just a general path to take to debug such a problem.  I started by making sure all objected are nil'd on memory warning etc.. hard with ARC because.. well who knows what's going on.

Any general direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the generic breakpoint to break "On Throw"? This will stop the app as soon as the exception is raised, rather than after it traverses the entire stack (uncaught). Very useful. Brief instructions:

1. Go to Breakpoint tab in XCode (6th from left in the left side pane).
2. Click + button in bottom left
3. Choose Add Exception Breakpoint
4. Keep the defaults by pressing done

I developed for 5 months before I learned about this basic function in the Debugger (Sept 30, 2011) video from iPad and iPhone Application Development course from Stanford in iTunes U (free).

Enjoy,

Damien

Answer (score 0):

ARC is definitely your friend - stick with it and your life will be much easier. First things first: Run your application under instruments (simulator is fine to start) for "Zombies". Hunt down any red "leaks" detected until none are left.